# How to delete xml Dom document in php

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'd search for this problem and find some questions but they didn't mention to my error...

I'm trying to remove a child of my DOM document and when I type the `$x->removeChild($key);`  function, nothing happend...

```
$xmlreq = new DOMDocument;
$xmlreq->loadXML($xmlStr);
$x = $xmlreq->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach($x as $key)
{
    if (substr($key->nodeValue,0,3)=="{{{" and substr($key->nodeValue,-3)=="}}}")
    {
        $field = explode("|",substr($key->nodeValue,3,strlen($key->nodeValue)-6));

        if((int)$field[3]==0)
        {
            if(trim($_POST[$field[2]])=="")
            {
                $x->removeChild($key);
            }else{
                $key->nodeValue = trim($_POST[$field[2]]);
            }
        }elseif((int)$field[3]==1)
        {
            if(trim($_POST[$field[2]])=="")
            {
                $errors.="";
            }else{
                $key->nodeValue = trim($_POST[$field[2]]);
            }
        }else{

        }



    }
}

header("content-type: application/xml");
print $xmlreq->saveXml();
```

and this is my xml:

```
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
<command>
<check>
<contact:check xmlns:contact="http://epp.nic.ir/ns/contact-1.0">
<contact:id>ghhg-ghgh</contact:id>
<contact:id>45</contact:id>
<contact:id>45</contact:id>
<contact:id>45</contact:id>
<contact:authInfo>
<contact:pw>1561651321321</contact:pw>
</contact:authInfo>
</contact:check>
</check>
<clTRID>TEST-12345</clTRID>
</command>
</epp>
```

and I want to delete one of `<contact:id>45</contact:id>`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName(): This function returns a new instance of the class DOMNodeList of all matched elements.`

Comment: and I used foreach to get every elements

Comment: @DoSparKot is correct - you have created a copy of `$xmlreq` into `$x` but you do not save `$x` or, presumably, use it later.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop does nothing since the outer conditional is looking for a node where `nodeValue` starts with `{{{` and ends with `}}}`:

```
foreach($x as $key)
{
    if (substr($key->nodeValue,0,3)=="{{{" and substr($key->nodeValue,-3)=="}}}")
```

Additionally, there's no `removeChild()` method in [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/DOMNodeList). You probably want to fetch the node's parent first and call its [removeChild()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) method instead.

A possible alternative:

```
$x = $xmlreq->getElementsByTagName('*');
$remove = TRUE;
foreach($x as $key)
{
    if( $key->nodeName=='contact:id' && $key->nodeValue=='45' ){
        if($remove){
            $key->parentNode->removeChild($key);
            $remove = FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```